# How to force test kitchen attributes to be passed as integers?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to set some attributes for some cookbooks that I imported through my `kitchen.yml` file.

kitchen.yml:

```
---
...
attributes:
    some_cookbook:
        key: 1
```

The cookbook that I'm importing seems to require that the attribute `node['some_cookbook']['key']` be an integer. I went onto my virtual machine to look at the `dna.json` file that gets generated and I can see the following:

dna.json:

```
{
    "some_cookbook": {
        "key": "1"
    }
    "run_list": ["recipe[some_cookbook::default]"]
}
```

So, what I'm seeing here is that test kitchen does not preserve the type as an integer when creating the file above. If I change the file above and remove the quotes surrounding the value `1`, then the recipe runs fine. Is there anything I can do to make kitchen pass in the right type? Or, perhaps this is better resolved by the cookbook maintainer validating the attributes better?

Comment: Try forcing the Yaml parser? `key: !!int 1`

Comment: Also, it's legal to put JSON in YAML files.  `attributes: { "some_cookbook": { "key": 1 }}'

Comment: Both of these suggestions worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: any idea how to pass nil?

Comment: Using yaml notation like @coderanger pointed out `key: !!NilClass`